# Django: how to use fk on reverse inline

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have the following models:

**models.py**

```
class Tipo_mundo(models.Model):
    nome_tipo_mundo = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    descricao_tipo_mundo = models.TextField(max_length=600)



class Mundo(models.Model):
    nome_mundo = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    descricao_mundo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    atividades = models.ManyToManyField(Atividade, through='Jornada', related_name='mundos')
    tipo_mundo = models.ForeignKey(Tipo_mundo, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='mundos')
```

and i want to put Mundo inside the Tipo_mundo admin edit page. As an inline to add as many Mundo's as i want. Refering to the list of Mundos already created. I want to create and edit just like a normal inline

when i put admins like:

**admin.py**

```
class MundoInline(admin.StackedInline):
   model = Mundo
   extra = 1

class TipoMundoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = TipoMundoModelForm
   list_display = ('nome_tipo_mundo', 'descricao_tipo_mundo')
   inlines = [MundoInline,]
```

i get:
[do not want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hmxh.png)
i want:
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG5FA.png)
how can i do this???

Answer (score 0):

The difference between what you get and what you want is that the first is a Foreign Key (i.e., a `Mundo` can be associated with one and only one `Tipo_mundo` - this means you cannot select an existing `Mundo` from elsewhere), and the second is a many-to-many relationship (i.e., you can associate one Mundo with any number of `Tipo_mundo`s).

If you want to be able to create a list of `Mundo`s that you can choose to attach to any `Tipo_mundo` then your model structure needs to change. Instead of a foreign key, use `ManyToManyField` to connect the two models, e.g.:

```
tipo_mundo = models.ManyToManyField(Tipo_mundo, related_name='mundos')
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still want to each Mundo to have only one Tipo_mundo.  Can I specify it with a manytomany?

Comment: You could possibly do some post-save validation to check that the `Mundo` has not been assigned elsewhere, and if it has then raise a validation error - but it would be much more complicated than using a foreign key.